# how to set the default encoding in windows XP?

Tags: vb.net, file-io, windows-xp

im trying to open a file using StreamReader and ive to set a Encoding, but i want it to take the Default Windows Encoding... how can i change my windows Encoding ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regional and Language Options Control Panel Item;  Advanced tab.

Impacts the entire computer.

Comment: there's default language option there, but no default encoding.

Comment: The language setting in the advanced area affects the encoding.  Its not called "encoding" because the audience for this dialog is Joe Public not just developers.

Comment: There is no such thing in my Windows 7.