# Character missing from file in certain environments

Tags: c#, file-io, c#-2.0

This is a completely new one to me and I don't know where to begin. I have a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) subclass that loads data from old plain text files on our local network to populate itself.

The files have some header lines, then the data (each row of which is separated by a line of dashes) until a set number of lines per page (59) after which the headers repeat themselves.

Recently there was a demand to add support for data that was not originally needed. This data does not have the same number of header columns. Instead I decided to look for a special character that will be in each set of data. The code looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Load the work order information from the chart on the network.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="workOrder">Work order to load</param>
/// <param name="model">Model number of the work order to load. Loaded from MES if null.</param>
public WorkOrderInformation(String workOrder, String model)
{
    if (model == null)
        model = MES.getOrder(workOrder).Model;

    String fileLocation = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(WorkOrderLocation, model), workOrder.Insert(4, "-") + ".TXT");

    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(File.Open(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));

    int currentLineNumber = 0;
    while (!file.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = file.ReadLine();
        Logging.Log.writeLog(log, "Loaded line | " + line);
        currentLineNumber++;
        int lineOnPage =(currentLineNumber % 59);
        // Old way to determine if line contains data
        //if (lineOnPage >= 10 && lineOnPage % 2 == 0)
        if (line.Contains(((char)65533).ToString()))
        {
            Logging.Log.writeLog(log, "Line added to collection");
            string[] sections = line.Split(new char[] { '|' });

            if (sections.Length > 1)
            {
                UnitInfo newUnit = new UnitInfo(sections[0].Trim());
                for (int j = 1; j < sections.Length; j++)
                {
                    newUnit.Add(sections[j].Trim());
                }
                this.Add(newUnit.TestNumber,newUnit);
            }
        }
    }
    file.Close();
}
```

On my development machine (Windows 7) and one deployment machine (Windows 2000) it works perfectly. On another deployment machine (Windows XP) that character is simply not in the line. If I check my log that character is not written when I log the full line and statement to log "Line added to collection" is not reached.

I am running it on the same file on all 3 machines.

**EDIT:**

I have changed my logging to store the length of the line loaded instead of the line itself and confirmed that the character is simply missing from the `string`. On the machines in which it works the log says the lines have a length of 65 characters and on the one that does not it is 64.

**EDIT 2:**

I have decided to rethink the problem. Instead of searching for that special character I have decided to split the string ahead of time and check if the first value is a number:

```
double dummy;
if(double.TryParse(sections[0],out dummy))
```

Which gets my job done but I'm still very curious why this is happening and will leave this question open in the hopes of an explanation at least.

**EDIT 3:**

It seems more is broken than I thought. As [Dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/770230/dan) pointed out, the value I am searching for (0xFFFD) is actually the [replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29) which it obviously should not be. Unable to identify the character from the printouts I opened the file in a hex editor and discovered the character is question should be 0x00F8 (ø).

So it seems that StreamReader is either loading 0x00F8 as the replacement character or not at all. Now the question is why?

Comment: Could be an encoding issue. Here's a question that shows how to set it to the default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469163/how-to-set-the-default-encoding-in-windows-xp

Comment: @TyCobb Oh that would make sense. I didn't even know the encoding could be different based on the environment, but if that's the case I'd rather just use the StreamReader constructor that accepts an encoding parameter. How can I figure out which encoding Windows 7 is using? (So that I may use the same one since that seems to work)

Comment: Yea, I just wasn't sure what was easier for you test with currently. I am not sure where you would find it for Windows 7. I think it is just standard `Encoding.Unicode`. You could always just call `Encoding.Default` temporarily and breakpoint to see what you got on that machine.

Comment: @TyCobb Well while I waited I tried using `Encoding.Unicode` but that makes it interpret all characters as Asian. I checked `Encoding.Default` on my development machine and it was of the type `System.Text.SBCSCodePageEncoding` which I've never heard of. Then I went ahead and tried `Encoding.UTF8` which got the job done on my Dev machine but when I deployed the update to the XP machine it still doesn't work.

Comment: FYI "SBCS" stands for "single-byte character set".  This encoding uses ISO-8859-1.  
ISO-8859-1 (aka Latin-1) and UTF-8 encode ASCII identically; but ISO-8859-1 is a fixed-length (single-byte) encoding whereas UTF-8 is variable length (it can be single- or multi-byte).  
Joel (Spolsky) has explained this better than I could, see [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm extremely curious how you came up with the following code:

```
if (line.Contains(((char)65533).ToString()))
```

Unicode 65533 or 0xFFFD is a special character called the [replacement character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29). This character's purpose is to be used in place of some unknown or unrepresentable characters.

As such, it's presence in a line of text generally signifies there was some other character which for some reason cannot be reproduced. The reason could be encoding, font, etc.

The mere fact that you're **expecting** to find this symbol seems like a fundamental flaw. Where do you expect this character to come from? How would it end up in the file?

Comment: It's a character that I've never seen anywhere else but I got that value from looking at that the char value of the symbol in question while debugging. The files are not generated in house and are provided by one of our parts suppliers. It looks vaguely like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%98) but with a vertical line instead of a slanted one.

Comment: Well that would be the Greek letter Phi, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi, but the Unicode for Phi is most definitely not 0xFFFD. There must have been a mistake in identifying the character code, perhaps try opening it with a hex editor to double check.

Comment: Interesting. I will check when I get a chance. (Which could be a hot minute given the holiday).

Comment: It seems my memory of the character was fuzzy and it was the one that I had found before and not Phi. Checking the hex confirms it but this still doesn't solve the issue of StreamReader not loading the character properly. I have updated my question to reflect this information.

Comment: The character in question is (I believe) used in Scandinavian languages.  I'd say you need to go back to the parts supplier.  Perhaps the character is due to a glitch/type during the data entry and/or file generation process -- a not unreasonable hypothesis if you've not previously seen an accented character in the supplier data.  On the other hand, if the accented character is in fact "correct", you're probably going to have to deal with other accented or possibly even non-Western characters.

Comment: There may also be an "accent-less" workaround.  For example, in German, a character with an umlaut can be replaced with the equivalent unaccented character followed by 'e', for example, you'd replace "ä" with "ae".